# Maximum number of combinations going from AAA-000 to ZZZ-999

Tags: combinatorics

In the Philippines, car license plates are in the [A-Z,A-Z,A-Z]-[0-9,0-9,0-9] format.

Given this, how would you find out the maximum number of possible car license plates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$26^3 \cdot 10^3$ is what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

1st character can be chosen in 26 ways,2nd one in 26 and also third one in 26 ways,the numerals in the same way can be chosen in 10 ways in each case so the total no. of choices=$26^3\times10^3$